# Different hget results in different versions

Tags: redis

Using "Redis server v=3.2.1 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-4.0.3 bits=64 build=bcc0f4a36956ba3e"  all hget that I did get updated value from a hash and work nice.

Using "Redis server v=3.2.10 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-3.6.0 bits=64 build=c8b45a0ec7dc67c6" with same config file base hget return always nil. Using two new parameters: "list-max-ziplist-entries 512
list-max-ziplist-value 64" I can get hget working again, but if I change in redis master a value of object, 3.2.10 version will not update that value and 3.2.1 will.

3.2.1 is compiled from me and 3.2.10 is from CentOS.

I did not found any weird/error/warn log in client or server logs. I am trying to understand why I am getting nil or values that do not update. I waited sometime to full resync, but 3.2.10 continue showing nil or outdated value (I am changing manually values to test if 3.2.10 is getting updates or not).

Comment: If I remove /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb and restart redis service, it will update objects in full resync, but will not update again.

Comment: I saw dump using something near 1.8GB and maxmemory is 1.2GB. Probably because default maxmemory policy (I think is ttl), it will take long time to update. I increased maxmemory to something greater than 1.8GB and changed default policy to LRU. It started to work. Will now homologate this test and I will write feedback here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to do feedback. maxmemory was the problem. solved

Comment: Can you explain better how you resolved this? So if someone comes with the same problem there is a detailed solution to look at.